# Ant Design Pro + Redux form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, ant-design-pro

Is there a way to make use of redux form with ant design pro? 
I cannot figure out how to add form reducer to ant design pro project skeleton.

Comment: This type of question is off topic for Stack Overflow. There are coaching/mentoring solutions for something like this, like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io/), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is/), or [AirPair](https://www.airpair.com/).

Comment: What do you mean off topic? I cannot ask a question about how to use redux form with ant design pro?

Comment: It is hard to answer this type of question concisely because there are many ways you can implement redux form. We have no context to your project system / setup / architecture. How should we go about helping you? Instead, if you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you're trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions.

Comment: @user2490936 Are you wrapping your component with `Form.create()` before exporting it?

Answer (score 0):

Antd provides an excellent workflow for forms and no reason to use redux-forms with antd. The once-popular forms are now recommended to be replaced by more elegant solutions.